# Float to hex conversion - reverse engineering

Tags: data-conversion

I'm trying to do some reverse engineering on my heating system. Monitoring the CAN BUS results in receiving hexademical strings, for example: 
00 D0 68 D6 86 83 61 8F 
61 C0 02 5C 12 B5 02 5C 
12 78 04 39 04 03 05 02 
05 C4 04 5C 12 5C 12 5C 
12 5C 12 D0 68 00 00 00 
00 18 08 37 D2 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 15 75 F2 
F0 01 00 01 00 00 00 1F
I know that for example the temperature value of 22.5°C should be somewhere in there. 
So far I have tried to look for the following conversions:

Possibility 1: ascii to hex
22.5 = 32 32 2E 35

Possibility 2: float to hex conversion
22.5 = 0x 41 b4 00 00

However none of these resulted in a match.

What would be other possibilities to converted a float to a hex string?
Thx

note: the given string is just a small part of my can sniffer so don't look for 22.5 in my given string here. I'm just looking for other possible conversions.

Comment: Fixed point?  225 == 0xe1  Fahrenheit?  What might help is finding what changes when temperature changes, and what stays the same when you keep the temperature the same.

Comment: @TobySpeight nice try but no luck with your suggestion. Besides it would probably not work for negative temperatures. Anyhow... Your other suggestion to find out what changes when temperature does ... I already tried this, but also here no luck. There is too much data and too much changing data passing by that it is too hard to find anything useful...